# Pandas to_csv with multiple separators

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to convert a pandas dataframe to csv with multiple separators. Is there a way?

```
dataframe.to_csv(file.csv, sep="%%")
```

> Error: delimiter must be 1-character string

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way might be to use a unique single-character separator first, then replace it:

```
tsv = dataframe.to_csv(sep='\t') # use '\1' if your data contains tabs
psv = tsv.replace('\t', '%%')
with open('file.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(psv)
```

P.S.: Consider using an extension other than `.csv` since it's not comma separated.

Comment: what if there is a '\t' in field content?

Comment: @DennisLi: That's why I said "use a unique single-character separator."  If your data contains tabs, use something else as the separator.

Comment: Very difficult to implement in text-heavy big datasets. You'd risk replacing a character in filed content.... Any way of saving directly with multi-character delimiters?

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be some bugs with replace as John says, cause it can't promise the replaced character is the seperator.

Besides, as `to_csv` returned as a `string`, if the data is big, it migth lead to `memory error`.

Here is another feasible solution.

```
with open('test_pandas.txt', 'w') as f:
    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        l = map(str, row.values.tolist())
        line = '%%'.join(l)
        f.write(line+'\n')
```