# Python3 dataframe mutiple separators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to take my `df.to_csv` which is `sep="\t"` and turn that tab into two spaces instead.

This question is similar but the solution isn't working: [Pandas to_csv with multiple separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838197/pandas-to-csv-with-multiple-seperators)

`\s+` won't work as python will complain that its not a single char separator.

This works as its a tab:

```
df2.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, sep='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="", escapechar=None)
```

this throws *`TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string`*

```
df2.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, sep='\s+', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="", escapechar=None)
```

Comment: I'm confused at your question, but for multiple spaces `\s+`. Can you copy and paste the first couple of lines from your `csv` or create a sample dataframe?

Comment: Yes, it would be good to have a simple example that people can copy and run on their own to test. And the output you expect.

Comment: I think you need `quotechar='"'`  If using the parameter you need to set a single char between the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at using `to_markdown` instead of `to_csv`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':'aaa bbb ccc'.split(), 'col2':[1, 10, 1000], 'col3': [True, False, True]})
df.to_markdown('a.txt', tablefmt='plain', index=False)
!type a.txt
```

File:

```
col1      col2  col3
aaa          1  True
bbb         10  False
ccc       1000  True
```

Comment: what is `!type a.txt` doing ? and where are you setting double spaces ?

Comment: On a windows machine it is just printing the file back to my jupyter notebook.  On linux you would use !cat a.txt.   The '!' is a indicating run this command in the shell.

Comment: I still don't see where you put the two spaces? also this produces this error `ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'tabulate'.  Use pip or conda to install tabulate.`

Comment: Yes, you need to install the tabulate library to use pd.DataFrame.markdown.  It isn't explicitly defined.  I was just thinking this file format would satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy save text this will work:

```
np.savetxt(r"path\file.csv", your_df, delimiter='  ')
```

Comment: this produces more errors on this line` np.savetxt(r"test2.csv", df2, delimiter='  ')
 raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e  %.18e')`

Answer (score 0):

The [answer on the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838197/) does seem to work without installing `tabulate` (trivial step really).  Self-contained example:

```
import pandas as pd

# from @Scott Boston's example frame...
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':'aaa bbb ccc'.split(), 'col2':[1, 10, 1000], 'col3': [True, False, True]})

# from @Scott Boston's answer...
# df.to_markdown('a.txt', tablefmt='plain', index=False)


# use a "weird char" for the sep value (well, weird to your data).  No file name...
temp = df.to_csv(sep='§')

temp = temp.replace('§', '  ')
with open('file.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(temp)
```

[image]